# Why do we need "struct" key word when declare certain variable

Tags: c++, sockets

In C++, when we declare a variable, we can do

```
A a;
```

Where A is a class name.
But in some cases, we add "struct" before the class name.

```
struct sockaddr_in addr_serv;
```

Is the "struct" here necessary?  why?

Comment: If a struct and a function have the same name, the `struct` adjective differentiates.

Comment: In C++ it is not necessary, it is optional (except in some specific cases).   In C, it is necessary (although can be avoided using an additional `typedef`) because the type is actually `struct sockaddr_in` not `sockaddr_in`.    When writing code that uses a C header (such as posix sockets headers, as in your case) a lot of available sample code is written in C, even though usable in C++ - so we end up with C++ code using that approach.